# Set up responder url(s) for OpenAM OCSP validation

Tags: openam, ocsp

I am trying to configure OpenAM 12.0.0 Build 8410 with OCSP validation
user. According to documentation, openam should pull ocsp responder address
from AIA of my certificate. However, in my case it does not pull, still
gives out CertPath:verify failed error. Is there any required configuration
I am missing?
A workaround would be putting all OCSP responder urls in default server and site configurations. But that fails since I do not know the appropriate separator could be used in the field. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem is associated with the version of Java I used in deploying openAM. There is no need to put the responder URL in that field as long as your certificate has AIA extension.